# How can I click on this child node / descendant using C# Selenium?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, css-selectors

**TL;DR: The developer had bound the jQuery click listener to the parent div, not the child span that I had been trying to click.**

---

I'm trying to click the delete button that is in the span tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="user j isotope-item" data-id="5362" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="delete-x">
        <span title="Delete">x</span>
    </div>
    <div class="name longText" title="Edit Location">
        Jkogo Rqrqn
    </div>
</div>
```

C#:

```
    public void DeleteUser(IWebDriver webDriver, long userId)
    {
        var deleteButton =
            webDriver.FindElement(
                By.CssSelector($"#userlist-container > div[data-id='{userId}'] > div.delete-x > span"));
        deleteButton.Click(webDriver);
    }
```

I printed to Console and it looks right/is getting the id at least:

```
#userlist-container > div[data-id='5362'] > div.delete-x > span
```

I'm stumped on how to click on this child element! Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue? any exception thrown?

Comment: It times out trying to find the element. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:57337/session/645e9e7262d821921f0d0c9061287907/element timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Comment: Nevermind; I got it to work. See Andrew's answer below and my comment in reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.xpath($".//div[@data-id='{userId}']/div/span")).Click(webDriver);
```

but possibly delete action is calling not by span click. In this case nothing happens after the click and you need to find more correct element for this. Somethimes this is parent element, sometimes parent-of-parent.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work thanks to your explanation: clicking the span doesn't work, but going one level up does! Which is weird, because when you do an inspect element in Chrome, the element it points to when you right click on the "X" button *is* the span. It seems like that should work but it doesn't for whatever reason. So the XPath that worked was: $".//div[@data-id='{userId}']/div"